# schedule two tasks subsequently in android

Tags: java, android

i want to perform 2 tasks.
First should repeat once in every 10min
Second should repeat every minute.
Example
Opening a website in first task
Opening another website in second task.
Thanx in advance

Comment: i tried using timertask for both the task.but am getting force close and it says can't create handles inside thread tat has not called looper.prepare()

Comment: You need only 1 task every minute. That task just has to do something in addition every 10th time it is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the scheduling part you can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

For instance:

```
public class TaskScheduler {
    public static void startScheduling(Context context) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 600, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Then inside your receiver class you can start an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(intentService);
    }
}
```

`MyService`looks roughly like:

```
class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() { 
        super(MyService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

And finally, don't forget to register `MyReceiver` in the manifest file:

```
<receiver 
   android:name="Your.Package.MyReceiver">
</receiver>
```

As well as your service:

```
<service 
   android:name="...">
</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `AsyncTask`, there is explanation and example here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html