# alarm in my application

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarm

i want an alarm in my app that every 10 minutes send a notification even if my app is close
and stop after 2 Hours
i am really need it

i wanna someone professional in alarm to help me please,it is for my GP i should submit it tomorrow

any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a very detailed answer about how to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414839/schedule-two-tasks-subsequently-in-android/10415004#10415004).

Regarding your particular scenario. You can add a `stopScheduling` method to your scheduler, using the [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) method:

```
public class TaskScheduler {
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    public static void startScheduling(Context context) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 600, pendingIntent);
    }

    public static void stopScheduling() {
       mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

So when you want to stop the scheduling you can call that method.

Now I am not aware of any simple method that would cause the `AlarmManager`to stop after 2 hours by itself but you can write another scheduler that would start after 2 hours to remove the first scheduler.

I suggest you to do it **step by step**. First try implementing a simple alarm and play with the parameters to see how scheduling work and then try removing this alarm. Once this work, you'll easily do the rest as it's just some a basic programming task. Also please read the detailed answer that I have written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414839/schedule-two-tasks-subsequently-in-android/10415004#10415004) as it provides all the information needed to setup a basic alarm.

Comment: if you excuse me i will tell you what exactly how my app work,first user press button then alarm should start then after 10 mins the alarm will send a notification has 2 buttons if he press YES then the alarm will complete,if he said NO the alarm will stop, and after 2 hours the alarm will stop! if you can help me with code for my case,  you will save my life, please be my HERO and help me

Comment: I have added more details in my answer on how you can remove an alarm as well as a hint on how to kill it after 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you so much, but can i ask you to give me your Email ? please?

Comment: if u don not, it is ok, can i ask you about what is the first step in put alarm in my code, i am really confuse i still read from 6 hours and i have no idea how can i start, please tell me, you will save my life :(

Comment: @Maha It's not that I don't want to help you. It's just that I have a lot of work to do too. I suppose you have read all the resources posted here. What is it that you don't understand? Do you have any problem seeing the big picture and how all those pieces fit together?

Comment: i read ALARM MANGER Doc. and some tutorials and i read your post, but still i have a lot of question,How can i start?what is the first code that i should write it?can you please tell me?

Comment: First code that you should write is the `TaskScheduler`class (you can choose the naming convention that you are the most comfortable with, I like to call it `xxxScheduler`. Choose the right delay (I think it's in Milliseconds), read the documentation to understand each parameter.
Then write the `BroadcastReceiver` that will receive the signal from the alarm and write the `IntentService` that will be called from the `BroadcastReceiver`. Finally, don't forget to register both the `BroadcastReceiver` AND the `IntentService` in the manifest.

Comment: Oh and don't worry too much about stopping it after 2 hours and such. As I said, do it step by step, start simply with one alarm and understand how it works. Then you'll handle the stopping part.

Comment: THANK YOU,i put it in separate class extends service,Am i right?

Comment: Yes separate classes. You'll have 3 classes: one for the Alarm, one that will extend from `BroadcastReceiver` and another one that will extend from `IntentService`.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

[Here is an example](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)

Comment: thank you for amazing tutorial, i am read it all,if i have any question in this tutorial can i ask you later?

Comment: if you have a specific question about something that you have a problem with post a new question and include any relevant source code and/or error logs in your question.